# Emulate HTML5 Datalist with TextArea with Javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I found a great feature in HTML5 that allows a list of items to be presented to the user.  The user selects an item and it is placed into an input.

```
<input type="text" list="cars" />
<datalist id="cars">
  <option>Volvo</option>
  <option>Saab</option>
  <option>Mercedes</option>
  <option>Audi</option>
  <option>Hyundai</option>
</datalist>
```

Unfortunately, I need the input to be a textarea to allow for multiple line user entry.  Further, I can't use HTML5.  Is there any way using JavaScript (jquery, bootstrap, etc...) that will make this happen?  This will be implemented on an asp.net C# page.

Disclaimer: I am a relative newbie in the world of JavaScript.  Apologies if this has previously been asked; I have spent two days looking for a solution.

Comment: Are you searching something like this?

https://sean.is/poppin/tags/

See example 4, it has an autocomplete... I don't know if you can force choices on a fixed list, but maybe it could have some options for that

Comment: As I thought, in taggle you can set allowedTags: [Array=[]] option to deny any entry outside the array

Comment: Thanks @Sycraw.  So close.  I don't want the tag functionality.  Hitting ENTER should create a NewLine in the textarea.  The functionality I am trying to provide is this:  The user can select from a list of some predetermined multi-line text items or enter new text.

Comment: If I've understood you (not sure about that) you can reach this result working on css, adding the rules  "display: block;float: none;" to the ".taggle" class

Comment: Close...  This is almost exactly what I want, except...  textarea rather than input and it can't be HTML5.  This page uses HTML5.  [link](http://www.ruralruins.com/temp/Example1.htm)